# how recursion processing under the hood

Tags: recursion, tail-recursion

It should be fundamental question about recursion.

Simple code:

```
func fact(n int) int {
    if n == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return n * fact(n-1)
}
```

how the line `n * fact(n-1)` will be processing under the hood by general programming languages, C++, Java, Go...

In my understanding the line `n * fact(n-1)` will create expression on the fly like
`n * n-1 * n-2. ...` So executable program will prepare expression according to incoming functional parameter. Also how will be processing simple recursion and tail recursion under the hood. Could you add more details, any useful docs.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not tail recursive. The last operation is n * fact result

Answer (score 1):

You can use [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) to see what's happening "under the hood" for C++ and Go. (As well as a few other languages.)

If you modify your algorithm to one of the languages (such as C++), godbolt will show you the assembly language that is generated.  You can't get much more "under the hood" than knowing whats happening with the registers and how it branches in assembly.

Of course, it requires you to understand assembly.  But your example is actually quite a simple one.

Here is a quick C++ example (of your code) you can paste into godbolt:

```
int fact(int n);

int main()
{
   fact(5);
}

int fact(int n) 
{
    if (n == 0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * fact(n-1);
}
```

Hope that gives you new insights into what is going on behind the scenes.